# Vue keep alive doesn't cache again after $destroy

Tags: vue.js

I want to remove my component from the keep-alive cache sometimes.

First I test that the component is in the cache by following this steps:

1. the the app component I click "goto foo".
2. in foo I click "get random number" which give me a number.
3. then I hit "back" (in the browser) and return to app/bar component.
4. click on "goto foo" again - and the number still there.

So far I see that keep alive is working.

5. now I want to remove this component from the cache. so next time I visit it will get initial state.

   - to do that I click - "remove from keep alive" (it just called to $destroy and nothing more).
6. I hit "back" (in the browser) and return to app/bar component.
7. click on "goto foo" again - and the number NOT there - okay.
8. now I expected keep alive to store my component in the cache, so I click on "get random number" which give me a number.
9. then I hit "back" (in the browser) and return to app/bar component.
10. click on "goto foo" again - **and the number is NOT there - the cache was not working**.

How can I solve this problem? how to remove the component from the keep alive cache and still make it cacheable next time?

Here the source code in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-composition-keep-alive-62riy)

Comment: Vue documentation suggests not to manually destroy a component but rather use v-if to add and remove it from DOM. I think you can also do something on the similar lines. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy

Comment: Not sure if there another way..

Comment: using v-if would solve your issue, right? Otherwise you'll have to manually mount the component again which I feel is not required.

Comment: what is porpose of remove and create again? if you want renew data, so store required data properties to another property and when need renew just re assign them

Comment: When using `$destroy()`, it leads me to memory leaks. 
In Vue Devtools, the `router-view` is kept si keep-alive works, but then if I destroy this page, each time I re-enter on the same page, a new `router-view` is created. 
It seems like the cached view in keep-alive is pointing on a destroyed component, so it cannot render the component so it creates a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend taking a look at the source code for `keep-alive`, it should give you a clearer idea of what exactly is going on and what's possible:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0baa129d4cad44cf1847b0eaf07e95d4c71ab494/src/core/components/keep-alive.js

I took a look myself and it looks like there is support for purging cache entries using `include` and `exclude`. Below is an example I've put together illustrating how it might be done:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    red: {
      template: `<div style="color: red">red: {{ num }}</div>`,
      
      data () {
        return { num: Math.random() }
      }
    },
    
    blue: {
      template: `<div style="color: blue">blue: {{ num }}</div>`,
      
      data () {
        return { num: Math.random() }
      }
    }
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      exc: '',
      type: 'red'
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    async purge (name) {
      if (this.type === name) {
        this.type = false
      }
      
      this.exc = name
      
      await this.$nextTick()
      
      this.exc = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <keep-alive :exclude="exc">
    <component :is="type"></component>
  </keep-alive>
  <button @click="type = type === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red'">Toggle</button>
  <button @click="purge('red')">Purge Red</button>
  <button @click="purge('blue')">Purge Blue</button>
</div>
```

I'm temporarily setting the value of the `exclude` prop to purge the cache entry, then setting it back to blank so that subsequent components can still be cached.

In your example I suggest emitting an event from the child to tell the parent to remove the child rather than having the child destroy itself.